# loading combobox with datasource

Tags: c#

i want to fill a combobox with data from the database when the page load 
I had written the code as below

```
private void QuotationForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("hghjgvhg");
            comboboxload();
        }




 public void comboboxload()
        {

            OleDbConnection oleDbConnection1 = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connString);
            oleDbConnection1.Open();
            OleDbCommand oleDbCommand1 = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("Select jobpk,jobecode from  jobcodemastertable",oleDbConnection1);
            OleDbDataReader reader = oleDbCommand1.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("jobpk", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("jobcode", typeof(string));
            dt.Load(reader);
            cmbjobcode.ValueMember = "jobpk";
            cmbjobcode.DisplayMember = "jobcode";
            cmbjobcode.DataSource = dt;
            oleDbConnection1.Close();  
        }
```

it doesnot deturns an error or exception but doesnot load the combobox with data values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to bind datatable's view with combo box

```
cmbjobcode.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
```

Answer (score 7):

try this

```
comboBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
comboBox1.ValueMember = "id";
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "name";
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the DataBind method

```
dt.Load(reader);
cmbjobcode.ValueMember = "jobpk";
cmbjobcode.DisplayMember = "jobcode";
cmbjobcode.DataSource = dt;
//here
cmbjobcode.DataBind();
oleDbConnection1.Close();
```

Comment: is data databind()  is an inbuilt function;

Answer (score 0):

You have to call DataBind method on your combo. Thats why its not populating.

Comment: In VS2008, I don't have a DataBind() method in the ComboBox class.  What do I do instead?