# Binding class object to a Combobox (when there is no reference of that class)

Tags: c#, class, combobox, load

In UI layer, I want to bind a combo box from Binding list of a class. This class is available  business entity as a separate project which is not referenced in UL layer.

```
    //UI Layer
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "CustomerID";
        comboBox1.DataSource = new CustomerFacade().getCustomers();
    }
}

//Facade Class
public class CustomerFacade
{

     public BindingList<Customer>  getCustomers()
    {

        BindingList<Customer> objects = new BindingList<Customer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            objects.Add(new Customer() { Name = "Customer " + i.ToString(), CustomerID = i });
        }

        return objects;
    }
}

//Business Entity Class
public class Customer
{
    public Int32 CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }


}
```

Here i have declared Customer class in the same project so it is working fine. But if i keep this customer class in Business Entity (as a separate project) then it will not work without adding reference of Business Entity.

How do i load values or bind this combo box without adding reference of Business Entity?
Is there alternate way like converting it to Array or Array list which will bind my combo box?

Comment: Just out of curiousity, what's the issue with referencing Business Entity project ?

Comment: I have the same question as @Michael, what is your problem?

Comment: In my solution, I have two separate project for UI and UI Base. UI is having reference of UI Base. I am having this combo box in UI Base. The Business Entity is referenced in UI Project and not it UI Base.  I cannot take reference of Business Entity Project in UI base becase this same UI Base can be used for other UI projects (those UI projects will have different Business entity).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is an Interface for your Customer class. Place this interface in an new project (usually this project is called Contracts). Every project should reference the contracts project. In this way you can pass an object which implements the interface to another project which only has to know the interface.
I modified your code to show it. (i didn't test it)

```
//UI Layer
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "CustomerID";
        comboBox1.DataSource = new CustomerFacade().getCustomers();
    }
}

//Facade Class
public class CustomerFacade
{

     public BindingList<ICustomer>  getCustomers()
    {

        BindingList<ICustomer> objects = new BindingList<ICustomer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            objects.Add(new Customer() { Name = "Customer " + i.ToString(), CustomerID = i });
        }

        return objects;
    }
}

//Business Entity 
public class Customer : ICustomer
{
    public Int32 CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

//Contracts
public interface ICustomer
{
    Int32 CustomerID { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Perhaps you can find more information about this by searching for "dependency injection". I think that's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Create for example `DataTable` in your `Business Entity` and use it as a datasource.

View [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9355877/loading-combobox-with-datasource) for details.

Or you can create array of strings (with `toString` method). Depends on what you want to show to user.